# LAZY Loading not working Spring Data 3.0.0 Hibernate - After Spring Boot Migration to 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

After migrating to Spring Boot 3.0 our integration test showed that deleting a user did not work properly.

The User has two properties, where both are defined the same (at least thats what I think, see below).

What I figured is, when I load the User object one of the properties of User are not loaded. Only if I define the property, which can not be loaded, as EAGER. If I now try to delete the User, this does not work because there is still the one property in DB which reference to the User.

I can not figure out whats the problem maybe I am missing something

My User Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user_model")
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    
    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private UserSettings userSettings;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private UserTermsOfUse userTermsOfUse;
    
    ...
}
```

User Terms Of Use which works to load

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_termsofuse")
@Data
public class UserTermsOfUse extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "accepted_termsofuse")
    private String acceptedTermsOfUse;

}
```

My Settings which does not load:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_settings")
@Data
public class UserSettings extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private User user;

    private String language;

    private String lastActiveClientId;

}
```

As you can see in my screenshot, when I load the entity User by ID it only shows the User Terms of Use ant not the User Settings
[image]

Just to make clear, they are within the DB :)
[image]

Hope Someone can point me to a correct direction

**UPDATE**

I made a sample project to prove it does not work. The test fails with an `NullPonterException` once I try to access the `UserSettings`.

https://github.com/de313e/SpringEagerLoadingIssue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly a bug for hibernate project.

Have opened a ticket for it [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16135) with both the bug described in the question from **kism3t** and also with what seems to be a workaround to bypass the issue.

Have checked the current non stable released versions of hibernate `6.2.0` and the bug is still there. So probably is undetected yet.

For the moment the following workaround seems to bypass the issue

```
   @Entity
   public class User {

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user") 
      private UserSettings userSettings;

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user") 
      private UserTermsOfUse userTermsOfUse;
  }
```

If the owning side of the `@OneToOne` declares the same fetchType of `Lazy` somehow the issue is bypassed.

So it works with

```
@Entity
public class UserTermsOfUse {

    ....

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  // <-------------
    private User user;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class UserSettings {

    ....

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  // <-------------
    private User user;
}
```

### Update

This was indeed a bug of hibernate project. It is solved in version **6.1.7.Final** and future versions.

Comment: Thanks, I already opend a ticket at spring-data as I thought it was an issue there. I will add an link to your hibernate ticket.. THX agin